# How can I find the terminal command to run a specific program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

In Windows, is it possible to find the terminal command to run a program from the icon's context menu? Here, I'm trying to find the terminal command to open each program from the icon's context menu, but I don't see the corresponding shell command anywhere in the context menu:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The terminal command is the path to the .exe file your question makes little sense.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm asking whether it's possible to find the command to run a program from the icon's context menu. I don't see anything confusing about the question. Is there anything that I need to explain more clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a shortcut, go to "Properties" and then look at the value in the "Target" field.

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two parts to your question:

First how to open a command prompt already set to the correct location. In Windows-7 there is nothing built-in to do this for files. For folders in Windows-7 you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and get `Open command window here` menu option. This [blog post](http://www.amilkhanzada.com/2012/03/command-prompt-here-for-files-and.html) claims to have a registry hack to make it work for files but I have not verified it.

[image]

Second once at the location what file to execute and what if any parameters to add. You can see this on the "Shortcut" tab on the "Properties" Windows for the selected file.

[image]